# Is it common to write only one "as" in a comparison?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, comparisons

This is a bit hard to explain, so here's an example:

> Hanging above the door was a huge smiley face put there to greet
>   visitors. I hoped the people inside were just **as** friendly.

Is this a common or grammatical construct? If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: Your example is grammatically correct and it is fairly common. There are other instances in which you would use "as" twice but I feel somebody else would be able to explain when it is necessary better than I am able to.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter whether it's common or grammatical, because using the single *as* here seems to me to be an odious bit of bad writing, hence undesirable.  You could add *as that* at the end to make the comparison explicit without clumsily repeating “huge smiley face”.

Comment: @jwpat7 ...as friendly as that?

Comment: @janoChen, yes.

Comment: @jwpat7 why do you think it is "odious"?

Comment: @curiousdannii, I see it as lazy and vague.  For example, the missing part of the sentence might be any of “as the door”, “as the face”, or “as the visitors”; the idea that it could only be the second of these is specious.  (Note, adding “as that” at the end likewise is a bit vague, but perhaps not so vague as to be odious.)

Comment: @jwpat7 That's how language works. All language is vague to some extent, so we aim to speak efficiently and only add qualifiers when we think there is a reasonable chance our listeners might misunderstand us.

Comment: @curiousdannii, efficiency is all very well, but ordinarily is not sufficient grounds for sacrificing clarity, sense, or elegance.

Comment: @jwpat7 On what grounds do you say that? Grice's Maxims aren't without disagreement but they serve pretty well for English at least.

Comment: @curiousdannii, perhaps I don't understand your last comment. Anyhow, while my arguments for most of my assertions may be nonstellar, it seems to me that [Grice's Maxims](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html) are consistent with my comment of 30 minutes ago.  One maxim (#4, quoted below) suggests brevity (efficiency), while two (#4 and #3) suggest clarity and sense.  #4 also says "be clear" before it says "be brief": “The maxim of manner, when one tries to be as clear, as brief, and as orderly as one can in what one says, and where one avoids obscurity and ambiguity”.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Your objection to the absence of 'as that' is ostensibly based on the difficulty of telling what 'as friendly' refers to. However: a) the context provided by the preceding sentence makes it highly unlikely that the referent of 'as friendly' would be misunderstood, and b) adding 'as that' to the second sentence would do nothing to clear up any possible confusion. In short, there are no reasonable grounds for finding fault with the standard of writing represented by the OP's query text.

Comment: The expression **just as** is often used in the sense of time, to express something that occurred very recently i.e. "the building collapsed *just as* he arrived". But *just* also means "exactly", "precisely", "absolutely" etc. and in the OP's sentence I had no difficulty with understanding it.

Comment: It is not unreasonable to expect something of a reader. If a reader misunderstands that the writer means "as friendly as the door", then I think the reader is in need of remedial help, not the writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "equative" construction is normally "as + adjective/adverb + as", but there are many instances in which we omit something because our listeners/readers will understand perfectly without the complete expression.

In this case, the full sentence might be: "I hoped the people inside were just as friendly as the huge smiley face."

But "as the huge smiley face" doesn't bear repeating. So we don't.

For a similar example, still in the realm of comparisons:

The first person I met was brazenly ugly. Fortunately, the second person I met was significantly more beautiful [than the brazenly ugly first person I met].